# Expression for variables in Smarty

Tags: php, forms, validation, expression, smarty

I am working with smarty templates in PHP and I would like to know if there is a short expression for this:

```
{if isset($data.name)}{$data.name}{/if}
```

such as in php we have:

```
<?= $data->name?? '' ?>
```

I want a form field to hold the data when it does not pass a validation, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Name" autofocus value="{if isset($data.name)}{$data.name}{/if}">
```

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [default](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.default.tpl) modifier to achieve a similar result to the null coalescing operator:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Name" autofocus value="{$data.name|default:''}">
```

Comment: Fine!!! it is exactly what I expected. thank you so much.